# NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in Chrome not incognito and Firefox locally with valid certs on nginx

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, nginx

A couple of weeks ago we implemented the SameSite cookie policy to our cookies. If I want to develop locally, I needed a certificate to get the cookies.

We're running a Node express server and that is reversed proxied to an nginx configuration where we add the cert.

```
# Server configuration
#
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name test-local.ad.ourdomain.com;
    ssl_certificate           /home/myname/.certs/ourcert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /home/myname/.certs/ourkey.rsa;
    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:9090;
        proxy_read_timeout  90;
        proxy_redirect      http://localhost:9090 https://test-local.ad.ourdomain.com;
    }
}
```

Now to the wierd part. We updated to Chrome 80 today, and all of a sudden I got an HSTS issue. I was unable to access site even if I wanted to (no opt in possibility). I tried to clear that inside chrome://internals/#hsts, and that worked. However, I still get `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` but I now have the opt in alternative.

Accessing it from Chrome Incognito mode works like a charm, no issues there. Same with Firefox, no issues there either. It says Certificate is Valid, green and pretty. Checked here as well: https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html and its 100% green.

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10 using Regolith.

My colleagues are using same cert, also Chrome 80, but they're running Mac, no issues there in Chrome.

Any idea? I tried to clear Browser settings, no change.

Comment: Same issue, on one of our public-facing websites. Common details: Chrome 80, Ubuntu 18.04. Same symptoms: Firefox ok, Chrome incognito ok, Chrome bad. Your solution below points out we have a chaining mis-configuraton; waiting on IT to fix things. Thanks.

Comment: I'm happy it was of help. This must be a bug in Chrome 80 on Ubuntu that causes this. Or have they introduced a stricter security setting to early?

Comment: I looked through their git log and didn't seen anything specific. This looks like the class of issue where a previous ignored problem is now not ignored. Possibly a side effect of some other change. No idea why it's only on Ubuntu (or linux).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have some great news!

We're using the same cert on our cloud dev environments (however, they are in pfx form). Locally I run Linux as mentioned, and I had to convert the pfx to a RSA file and a CRT file.

I entered our dev domain on this site: https://whatsmychaincert.com/ and it downloaded a *.chain.crt file. Together with my old crt file, and this command:

`cat example.com.crt example.com.chain.crt > example.com.chained.crt`

In Nginx I then referenced the `.chained.crt` file.

Now Chrome accepts my local, secure webpage.

Answer (score -4):

We had the same issue and fixed it following [petur 's solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60091443/1895419)

Comment: You should consider upvoting my answer and maybe do a comment. This is however wrong.

Comment: Sorry @petur, I wasn't allowed to comment on your answer. Just wanted to confirm it, I realise my answer was not very clear, Hope it is now.
Also, I upvoted your answer.